# Read error message from batch file from c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have this method that read the message of batch file that the application run automatically.
The code for run the batch file is this:

```
    private void ProcessFile(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;
            String percorsoFiles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameFileBat"];
            String command = "@" + percorsoFiles;
            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // *** Redirect the output ***
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
            // *** Read the streams ***
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            if (output.Contains("ERROR") || error!="")
            {
                //da verificare
                EventLog.WriteEntry((String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error), EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            EventLog.WriteEntry((String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output), EventLogEntryType.Information);
            log.Info("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
            log.Info("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
            //Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
            process.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("error, see log file ", EventLogEntryType.Error);
            log.Error("errore: " + exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("***Start timer again***", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            if (aTimer != null)
            {
                aTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the script:

```
 @echo off

    setlocal
    set LOCAL_PATH="C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001"
    set INSTRUMENT_NAME=41IT.Poros.PORO001
    echo Copying files to MES server...
    robocopy %LOCAL_PATH% \\pmiitbolmes06\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\EXPORT *.* /R:2 /W:5 /MOV /log+:\\pmiitbolmes06\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\LOGS\LabInstr.log

    echo Transfer complete.
    endlocal
```

This code found but I don't read the error message. For example if I run the script but I don't have a permission for write on destination folder, in the log file I read this error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Dec 11 10:39:18 2014

   Source : C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001\
     Dest : \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:2 /W:5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       2    C:\41IT.Poros.PORO001\
        New File               0    test.txt
2014/12/11 10:39:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.

Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
2014/12/11 10:39:23 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Destination Directory \\servername\LabInstr_Backup$\41IT.Poros.PORO001\EXPORT\
Access is denied.
```

I read this error messaage only from the log file but I can't read from application.
How can I fixed it?

Comment: Why don't you print the error (if there is any) in your `if statement` ? I don't get it: if you want to be notified of the error, simply use `Console.WriteLine(error);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error message found in the log file is not an error coming from the command launched (i.e. cmd.exe) but a returned message coming from robocopy containing an error message. That's why the error content is in "output" and not in "error".
If you write in your script this:

```
@echo off
sdsdfsdfsd
```

You will get this error coming from the command launched:

```
'sdfsdfsdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should write this for avoiding deadlocks:

```
process = Process.Start(processInfo);
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

instead of this:

```
process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Finally, you should use exit codes in order to get proper errors and write your script like this:

```
...
robocopy %LOCAL_PATH% \\pmiitbolmes06\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\EXPORT *.* /R:2 /W:5 /MOV /log+:\\pmiitbolmes06\LabInstr_Backup$\%INSTRUMENT_NAME%\LOGS\LabInstr.log

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto finish

exit %ERRORLEVEL%

:finish
echo Transfer complete.
exit 0
```

On the C# side, you can use the exit codes:

```
var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
if (exitCode != 0 || error != "")
{
    error = exitCode > 0 ? output : error;
    EventLog.WriteEntry((String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error), EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

Robocopy error codes can be found [there](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html).